# Getting an inexplicable 500 error when accessing rss endpoint from node

Tags: node.js, curl, rss, node-request

I'm making a simple request to an rss feed:

```
var request = require('request');
var req = request('http://www.govexec.com/rss/contracting/');

req.on('error', function (error) {
  console.log('error:',arguments);
});

req.on('response', function (res) {
  var stream = this;
  if (res.statusCode != 200) return this.emit('error', new Error('Bad status code'),res.statusCode);
});
```

output is `error: { '0': [Error: Bad status code], '1': 500 }`

However, if I hit the url from the browser, or do a simple curl request, I get the correct response
`curl 'http://www.govexec.com/rss/contracting/'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a programming problem, per say.

Most websites do expect you to send the header *user-agent* with your request. It seems to be this way with the website you have provided too.

Fixing this is trivial, since you can use include the user-agent like so:

```
var req = request({
    url:'http://www.govexec.com/rss/contracting/',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'request'
    }
});
```

Comment: If this is the case then the response code sent from `http://www.govexec.com/rss/contracting/` is misleading, the response code should be 4xx indicating a client error, not 5xx indicating a server error.

Comment: @AlexChesters, what they're sending is a 500 and I suppose that's a problem in their software. Can't really do anything about that.

Comment: Correct, so I believe your answer that you can fix this by sending a user agent is incorrect

Comment: @AlexChesters, I've checked and it works when sending a user-agent.

Comment: Interesting @Andrius, seems like poor design on the API to send a 500 response code for what it is a client error.